# How to list the primary key column in SQLite faster?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have an .sqlite database that contains 4 500 000 small images (24 GB total) and has two columns. Here is the table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE `OldImages` (
`Id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
`Image`    BLOB NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `PK_Images` PRIMARY KEY(`Id`)
);
```

I decided to load the list of Ids into a `HashSet<long>` for faster runtime control of what's already in the database, and it took 10 hours of 100% disk activity to complete. Is there any better way to go about such a thing? Apart from keeping the list elsewhere in a simple binary file - which I will probably end up doing from now on, as it's 36MB and loads instantly.

Here is the C# code:

```
var results = new HashSet<long>();
using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand (Program.DbImages))
using ( var transaction = Program.DbImages.BeginTransaction())
{
    SQLiteDataReader reader;

    cmd.CommandText = $"Select Id FROM {table}" ;
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var result = reader.GetInt64(0);
        results.Add((result));
    }

    transaction.Commit();
}
return results;
```

Comment: You should rethink this strategy.  Depending on how many images you're displaying at once, it's probably better to just retrieve them from the database as needed, and cache them if required.

Comment: Even with a 24gig db stuffed full of blobs, there's no way it would take 10 hours to select a mere 4.5 million row ids from a table. Something is screwy, probably in stuff you're leaving out of the question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how does it perform without creating a transaction?

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's the thing, I just want to list the primary column (filenames, basically), the blobs can stay where they are. Maybe (i'm hoping) there's a better command for that, I'll be the first one to admit I don't know my SQL.

Comment: @Shawn a NTFS WD Blue HDD is all I can think of adding to the description. Otherwise I'm just calling the method shared here and giving it the {table} name.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis can't run a 10-hour-long test now, but getting rid of the transaction doesn't seem to do much for a smaller database I know the "list all Ids" completion time for.

Comment: Yeah, but you're not gonna display 4 million filenames at once, are you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey My plan was to use the in-memory list (hashset) as a way to reduce HDD load when checking maybe 1000 filenames' presence in the database every minute. I can do that now, I've saved the hashset binary after the 10-hour run. I was basically wondering whether there's a faster way than "Select Id FROM {table}" to achieve what I want :)

Comment: I don't think your SELECT statement is the problem.  I think all your time is being spent creating that hashset.  You can confirm that by running a StopWatch object.

Comment: Or, that Reader.Read method is executing a SELECT statement for *every individual record*, which is going to take a very long time indeed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey A quick test says converting 4.5 million random `long`s (including generation) to a `HashSet` takes less than 1.5 seconds.

Comment: I created a sample SQLite database and added 4.5 million random `long`s and a 4KB BMP BLOB. Took a while to create a 10GB file, but only 13.4 seconds to run your `SQLiteDataReader` code. I think something else is going on - perhaps show your actual `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: @NetMage I've added my table creation code to the original question. A smaller (700 MB) database with a similar rowcount (just no blobs) also takes long (~45 minutes) to list its primary key "IDs" using the same code. HOWEVER, only the first time after a system restart. Once it's "cached" (or whatever that behavior is called, maybe it's still in ram?) that same code's execution is very fast. I'm not sure a 10GB file can be "cached" the same way, but could you try the same code on your databse, only this time with a restart after table creation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out why that `SQLiteDataReader`  is so slow, let's just bypass it and use a better performing technique.

First, add [**Dapper**](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to your project.  You can obtain it from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper).

Then, add to the top of your class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Dapper;
```

I'm not sure how you're getting a connection with your current SQL data provider, but you'll need a connection string to do it with Dapper.

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
```

Then execute the following code:

```
var data = connection.Query<long>("SELECT Id FROM {table}");
var hashSet = new HashSet<long>(data);
```

Make sure you replace `{table}` with your actual table name from SQLite.

**See Also**
[SQLite Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Had to make it "new SQLiteConnection(myconnection);", Sqlconnection was telling me the server doesn't exist. However, the speed seems to be similar to my original code: 4.5 million rows in a couple-hundred-MB-table (no blobs) took 28 minutes. Second run (with the table already cached, I guess) took 3 seconds. Can't run the 24 GB database test for 10 hours now, but its process memory grows by ~1 MB/min, while the no-blob database grew at ~10 MB/min, so I'm guessing the retrieval is 10x slower for the blob table, which would again put it at least at 5+ hours.

Comment: So either SQLite isn't meant to be used this way at all (which brings us back to your first comment - "You should rethink this strategy." :-D), works super slow on an HDD (I will try SSD next), or there's something else I'm missing..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I should have tried defragmentation and HDD vs. SSD before questioning my code. These tests use Dapper (as proposed in the answer by Robert Harvey), but that in itself makes no speed difference.

150MB database, 2 000 000 rows, ~136 MB RAM:

```
A 2018 4TB WD Blue HDD = 6m 31s
same HDD after defragmenting the database file = 2m 32s
an old SATA Corsair Force3 120GB SSD = 8s
```

4 500 000 rows, ~300 MB RAM:

```
HDD = 28min
HDD (defrag) = 13min
SSD = 28s (with both Dapper and my original code)
```

Every test was preceded by a system reboot to prevent caching.

So I guess the rather obvious answer is:
Don't use HDDs (at least not 4TB WD Blue) for SQLite databases, and if you have to, at least defragment them regularly.

Comment: I have been running my tests in LINQPad. My 10GB database is on a WD Black 4TB HDD. I re-ran my query after re-starting LINQPad in 32-bit mode, and it is still running at 31 minutes. I restarted in 64-bit mode and it has been running 1 hour 13 mins. You might be right - caching from the data write may have greatly speed up the query.

Comment: I'd tried copying the file to my SSD and running your code (without the transaction) and it took less than 15 seconds. I restarted LINQPad before running the test and re-running it only reduced the time to 14 seconds. At least for me, SSD does seem to have made a big difference.